# Why are there questions tagged "untagged"?

Tags: support, tags

I noticed there are questions tagged [untagged](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) (actually, they are 8).

Why are there questions tagged with it?
I know that in past it happened when a question was migrated from another site that was not using any of the tag used from the receiving site, but that is not surely the case for some of those questions (for example, https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/posts/1660/revisions).

What made that tag appear in the site? What tags should be used for those questions that would replace the temporary [untagged](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that these questions had been tagged with a single-use tag (meaning it was only attached to one question). A single use tag without a tag wiki gets removed after a period of time. Any posts associated with these wiki-less single-use tags will get the [untagged](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) attached to it instead.

There is a post on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) that explains a bit about this. If the tag gets a tag wiki, then it won't be deleted even if it's attached to only one question.

Comment: I thought that a question using a single tag would not get it replaced with [tag:untagged]. That explains all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When a question is migrated from another site, it may start as [untagged](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). This may not happen very often on Esperato SE, but I have seen it a few times on [Language Learning Stack Exchange](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

See also [Migrated SO question get an untagged tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233509/migrated-so-question-get-an-untagged-tag) on Meta SE.